# ListView showing Blank screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want a Background image and above that image some content will be there that should be vertically scrollable so that it should not get outside the image.

THe code is shown below

I am using the satck and one child is Image and the other is  listview to acheive this but still not able to find the correct solution..

```
 ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
               new Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        child: background.Row3
                    ),

                      Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Center(child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/Receipt.svg',height: 350,width: 200,),),/*************this is the main background image****************/

                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:100),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              ListView(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                children: <Widget>[  /********text above background image *******************/

                                  Center(
                                      child:Text('Beneficiary Details',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,color: Colors.black),)
                                  ),


                                  Center(
                                      child:Text('Sushita sen',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Colors.grey),)
                                  ),
                                  Center(
                                      child:Text('Reference Number',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,color: Colors.black),)
                                  ),

                                  Center(
                                    child:Text('73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Colors.grey),)
                                    ),

                                  Center(
                                    child:Text('73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Colors.grey),)
                                    ,),

                                  Center(
                                    child:Text('73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Colors.grey),)
                                    ,),

                                  Center(
                                    child:Text('73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Colors.grey),)
                                    ,),

                                  Center(
                                    child:Text('73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Colors.grey),)
                                    ,),

                                  Center(
                                    child:Text('73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Colors.grey),)
                                    ,),

                                  Center(
                                    child:Text('73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Colors.grey),)
                                    ,),
                                ],
                              )


                            ],
                          )

                            ,)


                        ],
                      )

                    ],
                  )

              ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
   );
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why you have use stack as parent in ListView ? Does is requirement or you simply trying to showing List.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I correct it by placing ListView inside container

```
 home: ListView(children: <Widget>[
  new Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(child: Text("Hello")),
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                color: Colors.blue,
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: new NetworkImage(
                        "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/funny-face-baby-27701492.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill)),
          ),
          /*************this is the main background image****************/

          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
               Conatiner( /************This container will wrap the listview and will make it scrollable also *******/
                height:200,
                child: ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center(
                        child: Text(
                      'Beneficiary Details',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
                    )),
                    Center(
                        child: Text(
                      'Sushita sen',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                    )),
                    Center(
                        child: Text(
                      'Reference Number',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
                    )),
                    Center(
                        child: Text(
                      '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                    )),
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  )
]),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

@kriti sharma for background image inside the Stack widget kindly use [Positoned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widget on top of the Stack widget.

example:-

```
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/icons/categories/map.jpg",
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        ),
      ),
      // _buildGoogleMap(context),
      // _zoomminusfunction(),
      // _zoomplusfunction(),
      // _buildContainer(),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: and use ListTile Widget Inside The ListView Instead Of Center...
ListTile Deatils:- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html

Answer (score 2):

Actually it not black screen you got error like,

> Exception caught by rendering library
>   The following
>   assertion was thrown during performResize():
>
> Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.

I just added scrollDirection and shrinkWrap in you list.

```
                ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
```

Your whole code

```
home: ListView(children: <Widget>[
      new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(child: Text("Hello")),
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: new NetworkImage(
                            "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/funny-face-baby-27701492.jpg"),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill)),
              ),
              /*************this is the main background image****************/

              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Center(
                            child: Text(
                          'Beneficiary Details',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
                        )),
                        Center(
                            child: Text(
                          'Sushita sen',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                        )),
                        Center(
                            child: Text(
                          'Reference Number',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
                        )),
                        Center(
                            child: Text(
                          '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                        )),
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '73YHNUWD6EW7R34Y78HSDIF',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      )
    ]),
  );
```

[image]

Comment: Its still not working the same. It is not vertically scrolling inside the listview if I increase the data .... I want to know why its not scrolling ...I have already added the code you suggested then too....

Comment: You mean if i'm adding 50+ Text() . it not scroll right ?

Comment: actually i'm not clear what you actually trying to archive, Do this single list? what you use Stack and Two time ListView ?

Comment: I wanted the image in background and above that some text that should be vertically scrollable and it wrap around the the height of image.........means to say it should not overflow the image

Comment: I got the answer actually I have to put that listview inside some container by giving a fix height after that I will be able to scroll.Thanks a lot you partially solved my problem :)

Comment: yup true it partially solved, there is some unwanted widgets are there.

Comment: Ya I will optimize it